# Javascript function tidy up

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below you'll see a javascript/jQuery function I'm currently using:

```
            var forward = new RegExp('forward'),
                backward = new RegExp('backward'),              
                left = new RegExp('left'),      
                right = new RegExp('right');                

            if ( tweet.message.match(forward) ) {
                console.log('forward');
                body.addClass('forward');
                bodyRemoveClass();                          
            }

            if ( tweet.message.match(backward) ) {
                console.log('backward');
                body.addClass('backward');
                bodyRemoveClass();                          
            }

            if ( tweet.message.match(left) ) {
                console.log('left');
                body.addClass('left');
                bodyRemoveClass();                          
            }

            if ( tweet.message.match(right) ) {
                console.log('right');
                body.addClass('right');
                bodyRemoveClass();                          
            }
```

Everything works just fine, but I'm not 100% happy with the way it's written.
Basically what that does is, check if a given keyword *(forward, backward, left or right)*
are in a tweet *(tweet.message)*

I would like to know if there is a simple/cleaner way to achieve this.

Sorry but there is no online example...

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no need to use `match()` with `Regexp` here. You can do simple string matching with `indexOf()`. You can then avoid declaring all the `Regexp` at the beginning.

```
        if ( tweet.message.indexOf("forward") > -1) {
            console.log('forward');
            body.addClass('forward');
            bodyRemoveClass();                          
        }

        if ( tweet.message.indexOf("backward") > -1) {
            console.log('backward');
            body.addClass('backward');
            bodyRemoveClass();                          
        }

        if ( tweet.message.indexOf("left") > -1) {
            console.log('left');
            body.addClass('left');
            bodyRemoveClass();                          
        }

        if ( tweet.message.indexOf("right") > -1) {
            console.log('right');
            body.addClass('right');
            bodyRemoveClass();                          
        }
```

However, this is much more neatly accomplished with an array of classes:

```
// Store your 4 classes in an array
var classes = ["forward","backward","left","right"];
for (var i = 0; i<classes.length; i++) {

  // Check each class appearing in the message:
  if ( tweet.message.indexOf(classes[i]) > -1) {
     console.log(classes[i]);
     body.addClass(classes[i]);
     bodyRemoveClass();                          
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use a table-drive approach like this:

```
var tags = ["forward", "backward", "left", "right"];
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
    if (tweet.message.indexOf(tags[i]) != -1) {
        body.addClass(tags[i]);
        bodyRemoveClass();
    }
}
```

Keep in mind that any time you're repeating the same logic and the same strings over and over again, you should find a way to either drive your logic by iterating through a table, break the code out into a common function or something that prevents you from repeating code over and over again.  The popular lingo in software development these days for this is `DRY` (don't repeat yourself).

There was also no reason for test each individual match with a regular expression.  While they can be very handy when needed, `.indexOf()` is a lot faster when that's all that is needed.

Answer (score 3):

```
function TweetMatch(classToAdd){
    if ( tweet.message.match(new RegExp(classToAdd))) {
        console.log(classToAdd);
        body.addClass(classToAdd);
        bodyRemoveClass();                          
    }
}
TweetMatch('forward');
TweetMatch('backward');
TweetMatch('left');
TweetMatch('right');
```

etc.  (I see fellow commenters have gone ahead and made arrays to iterate over... depends upon how many directions you want :-D)

Answer (score 1):

This can be drastically shortened by capturing the matched phrase:

```
var match = tweet.message.match(/forward|backward|left|right/g);
for (var i = 0; match && i < match.length; i++) {
    console.log(match[i]);
    body.addClass(match[i]);
    bodyRemoveClass();
}
```

The only thing different in each of those `if` blocks is the phrase to be matched (which is the same as the name of the class to be added). Repetition like that can (and should) almost always be avoided.

Comment: this will match a maximum of **one** of the values in the regex, whereas the original function made it possible to match all of them at once.

Comment: @Aaron - That's not true (did you see my edit?). Actually, it has the *opposite* problem. It will loop over *all* matches, including duplicates.

Comment: Oops, I was looking at the original `if` statement. Maybe I should refresh once in a while, eh?

Comment: @Aaron - Well, I should have noticed that in the first place; then I wouldn't have needed the edit :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var directions = new Array('forward', 'backward', 'left', 'right');
$(directions).each(function()
{
    var regX = new RegExp(this);
    if (tweet.message.match(regX))
    {
        console.log(this);
        body.addClass(this);
        bodyRemoveClass();
    }
});
```

Comment: Are you trying to use jQuery here?  I don't think `$(directions).each()` will work and the $() function doesn't accept a plain array of strings.  Perhaps you meant `$.each(directions, fn)`.

Comment: note that there is nothing on the [jquery() doc page](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) that says you can pass an array of strings to that function.  I guess I'm not saying that it doesn't work, but it sure isn't documented.  It sure seems like `$.each()` which is [documented](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) would be a wiser choice.